# How to merge sorted vectors into a single vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have 10,000 `vector<pair<unsigned,unsigned>>` and I want to merge them into a single vector such that it is lexicographically sorted and does not contain duplicates. In order to do so I wrote the following code. However, to my surprise the below code is taking a lot of time. Can someone please suggest as to how can I reduce the running time of my code?

```
using obj = pair<unsigned, unsigned>
vector< vector<obj> > vecOfVec;  // 10,000 vector<obj>, each sorted with size()=10M

vector<obj> result;

for(auto it=vecOfVec.begin(), l=vecOfVec.end(); it!=l; ++it)
{
  // append vectors
  result.insert(result.end(),it->begin(),it->end());   
  // sort result  
  std::sort(result.begin(), result.end());
  // remove duplicates from result   
  result.erase(std::unique(result.begin(), result.end()), result.end());      
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the fact that your initial vectors were already sorted will not help much, if ever. Your data is huge, so it will take long time anyway. The only thing that I can suggest to speedup is to `reserve` the space of the merged vector before merging, because your merging operation is very slow and does a lot of moving.

Comment: what is `resultPairLeftRight` ?  Your code mentions it only once.

Comment: You write that `vecOfVec` contains 10,000 elements, and each `vector<pair<unsigned, unsigned>>` contains 10 million pairs.  Totally you should have 10,000 * 10 million = 100 billion pairs (NOT 100 million! 100 billion!).  If each pair fits 8 bytes, your `vecOfVec` should use about 800 Gbytes of memory.  Is this true?

Comment: lol @user31264, notice *"to my surprise"*

Comment: @user31264 As there are a lot of duplicates, therefore the over all size of resultVector is able to fit in memory

Comment: In the new version of your code you do 10,000 sorts, which also takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the fact that the vector in `vectOfVect` are sorted.

So detecting the min value in the front on the single vectors, `push_back()` it in the `result` and remove all the values detected from the front of the vectors matching the min values (avoiding duplicates in `result`).

If you can delete the `vecOfVec` variable, something like (caution: code not tested: just to give an idea)

```
while ( vecOfVec.size() )
 {
   // detect the minimal front value
   auto itc    = vecOfVec.cbegin();
   auto lc     = vecOfVec.cend();
   auto valMin = itc->front();

   while ( ++itc != lc )
      valMin = std::min(valMin, itc->front());

   // push_back() the minimal front value in result
   result.push_back(valMin);

   for ( auto it = vecOfVec.begin() ; it != vecOfVec.end() ; )
    {
      // remove all the front values equals to valMin (this remove the 
      // duplicates from result)
      while ( (false == it->empty()) && (valMin == it->front()) )
         it->erase(it->begin());

      // when a vector is empty is removed
      it = ( it->empty() ? vecOfVec.erase(it) : ++it );
    }
 }
```

If you can, I suggest you to switch `vecOfVec` from a `vector< vector<obj> >` to something that permit an efficient removal from the front of single containers (stacks?) and an efficient removal of single containers (a list?).

Answer (score 1):

If there are lot of duplicates, you should use `set` rather than `vector` for your result, as set is the most natural thing to store something without duplicates:

```
set< pair<unsigned,unsigned> > resultSet;
for (auto it=vecOfVec.begin(); it!=vecOfVec.end(); ++it)
    resultSet.insert(it->begin(), it->end());
```

If you need to turn it into a vector, you can write

```
vector< pair<unsigned,unsigned> > resultVec(resultSet.begin(), resultSet.end());
```

Note that since your code runs over 800 billion elements, it would still take a lot of time, no matter what.  At least hours, if not days.

Other ideas are:

- recursively merge vectors (10000 -> 5000 -> 2500 -> ... -> 1)
- to merge 10000 vectors, store 10000 iterators in a heap structure

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your code is the excessive use of `std::sort`. Unfortunately, the quicksort algorithm (which usually is the working horse used by std::sort) is not particularly faster when encountering an already sorted array.

Moreover, you're not exploiting the fact that your initial vectors are already sorted. This can be exploited by using a heap of their next values, when you will not need to call `sort` again. This may be coded as follows (code tested using `obj`=`int`), but perhaps it can be made more concise.

```
// represents the next unused entry in one vector<obj>
template<typename obj>
struct feed
{
  typename std::vector<obj>::const_iterator current, end;
  feed(std::vector<obj> const&v)
    : current(v.begin()), end(v.end()) {}
  friend bool operator> (feed const&l, feed const&r)
  { return *(l.current) >  *(r.current); }
};

// - returns the smallest element
// - set corresponding feeder to next and re-establish the heap
template<typename obj>
obj get_next(std::vector<feed<obj>>&heap)
{
  auto&f = heap[0];
  auto x = *(f.current++);
  if(f.current == f.end) {
    std::pop_heap(heap.begin(),heap.end(),std::greater<feed<obj>>{});
    heap.pop_back();
  } else
    std::make_heap(heap.begin(),heap.end(),std::greater<feed<obj>>{});
  return x;
}

template<typename obj>
std::vector<obj> merge(std::vector<std::vector<obj>>const&vecOfvec)
{
  // create min heap of feed<obj> and count total number of objects
  std::vector<feed<obj>> input;
  input.reserve(vecOfvec.size());
  size_t num_total = 0;
  for(auto const&v:vecOfvec)
    if(v.size()) {
      num_total += v.size();
      input.emplace_back(v);
    }
  std::make_heap(input.begin(),input.end(),std::greater<feed<obj>>{});
  // append values in ascending order, avoiding duplicates
  std::vector<obj> result;
  result.reserve(num_total);
  while(!input.empty()) {
    auto x = get_next(input);
    result.push_back(x);
    while(!input.empty() &&
          !(*(input[0].current) > x))  // remove duplicates
      get_next(input);
  }
  return result;
}
```